# Get td by src of th , Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php

I have table like this

```
<table>
<tr><th>test</th><td>mydata</td></tr>
<tr><th>test2</th><td>mydata2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to get the `td` where `th = test2`

```
$html = str_get_html('table.html)'
$table = $html->find('table',0);
$table->find('td[where th src = test2')->src # like this
```

Finally, I want to get `test2`, how can I do this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way to find an element based on text content(in PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser).
You can find the th with the text by looping through all the `th`s finding the one with the text and then getting the next sibling.

```
$html = str_get_html('table.html')
$table = $html->find('table',0);
$ths = $table->find('th');
$th = null;
foreach ($ths as $th){
    if ($th->plaintext = 'test2'){
        $td = $th->next_sibling();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: next_sibling() is what I want.It is quite useful function, thank you very much.